# Proving the set of real numbers is uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, real-numbers

Observing it is enough to define an injective function:
$$f:(0,1)^{\mathbb{N}}\to \mathbb{R}$$

For $\alpha \in (0,1)^{\mathbb{N}}$, we have $\alpha:\mathbb{N} \to (0,1)$.

We define $$f(\alpha)=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{2\alpha(n)}{3^n}$$

We need to show $f$ is injective by showing $f(\alpha)\neq f(\beta)$ for $\alpha \neq \beta$.

Suppose $\alpha \neq \beta$. Let $k$ be the minimal natural number with $\alpha(k) \neq \beta(k)$. We can assume, without losing generality, $\alpha(k)=0, \beta(k)=1$.

$$f(\alpha)=\sum^{k=1}_{n=0}\frac{2\alpha(n)}{3^n}+\frac{2\alpha(k)}{3^k}+\sum^{\infty}_{n=k+1}\frac{2\alpha(n)}{3^n}$$

$$\leq \sum^{k=1}_{n=0}\frac{2\alpha(n)}{3^n}+\sum^{\infty}_{n=k+1}\frac{2}{3^n}$$

$$=\cdot\cdot\cdot +\frac{2}{3^{k+1}}\cdot\bigg(1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3^2}+...\bigg)= \frac{3}{2}$$

$$\cdot \cdot \cdot + \frac{1}{3^k}$$

$$<\sum^{k=1}_{n=0}\frac{2\alpha(n)}{3^n}+\frac{2\beta(k)}{3^n}$$ Since $(\beta(k)=1)$

$$\leq\sum^{k=1}_{n=0}\frac{2\beta(n)}{3^n}+\frac{2\beta(k)}{3^k}+\sum^{\infty}_{n=k+1}\frac{2\beta(n)}{3^n}$$

$f(\alpha) < f(\beta)$, as required.

Is this proof of the uncountability of the set of real numbers okay? Tell me if I went wrong anywhere. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the factor $2$ for? How does that help? Why $2$ and not $43\pi$ or any other nonzero factor?

Comment: 2 was just used for simplicity, I suppose. I could've used any nonzero factor, as you say, but $43\pi$ is quite outlandish. Just picked the closest integer to one.

Comment: Unless you're saying the factor is unnecessary?

Comment: The closest integer to one is one. What was wrong with that? How does doubling the output of a function help make it injective??

Comment: Is there anything else wrong with the proof or are you nitpicking? You said yourself it can be any nonzero factor. It's arbitrary after that condition is satisfied.

Comment: The reason I've used 2 is that: 1. $2 \in \mathbb{N}$ 2. $2^{\mathbb{N}} \approx \wp(\mathbb{N})$, hence it's uncountable. I suppose I'm actually constructing an injective function $f : 2^{\mathbb{N}} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: May I suggest $\{0,1\}$ instead of $(0,1)$?

Comment: It's meant to be ${0,1}$ but I don't know how to use braces in LaTex without them disappearing... Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler injection into R.

For any binary sequence s that does not end in 1,1,1,1....
map s to $\sum_n s(n)/2^n.$

For any binary sequence s that does end in 1,1,1,1....
map s to 64 + $\sum_n s(n)/2^n.$